# Рендер формы и отображение ошибок rails 7 + turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Делаю регистрацию пользователя и обработку ошибок.
Возникла проблема, что по нажатию submit с неверно заполненными данными ошибки не показываются.

Что я упустил? Что надо сделать?

Заметил, что в Network вкладке приходит response html с ошибками и тд.
Если я правильно понял, то по нажатию submit рельсы должны изменить html полученный из response.

Модель юзера:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide :page_title, 'Registration' %>

<h1>Registration</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', resource: @user %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

shared/errors

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <div style="color: red">
    <h2><%= pluralize(resource.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В rails 7 теперь используется по умолчанию turbo frames.
И рендер формы надо поместить в такой фрейм.

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "user" do %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```